# Problemas al cambiar de pagina con "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch"

Tags: scroll

Necesito ayuda , os comento , estoy haciendo una aplicación donde necesito utilizar  "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" en varias vistas, el problema es el siguiente:

Cuando hago scroll y pulso el boton para cambiar la vista a otra pagina, primero me para el scroll y despues tengo que volver a pulsar para cambiar la vista.

Resumiendo que no me dejo cambiar la vista mientras el scroll esta funcionando

Encontre esta solución: [Using '-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' hides content while scrolling/dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801687/using-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-hides-content-while-scrolling-dragging) pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Alguna idea de porque hace eso, yo no consigo dar con la solución.

Mi HTML:

```
<div id="index"  style="display: block;">

        <div class="headerpage">
            <div class="header_left">

            </div>
            <div class="header_right">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bodyindex" class="scroll">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="img_ad"></div>

                    <div class="info_ad">
                        <p>Apple Watch Negro<br>250€<spam> . Hace 2h a 1 km de ti</spam></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="img_ad"></div>

                    <div class="info_ad">
                        <p>Iphone 6s plus Negro<br>550€<spam> . Hace 2h a 1 km de ti</spam></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="img_ad"></div>

                    <div class="info_ad">
                        <p>Bmw M3 Azul<br>6000€<spam> . Hace 2h a 1 km de ti</spam></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="img_ad"></div>

                    <div class="info_ad">
                        <p>Seat ibiza 97<br>2000€<spam> . Hace 2h a 1 km de ti</spam></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="img_ad"></div>

                    <div class="info_ad">
                        <p>Casa en oleiros<br>250000€<spam> . Hace 2h a 1 km de ti</spam></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Mi CSS:

```
.scroll{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
div#index{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }
div#index div#bodyindex{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
div#index div#bodyindex ul{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
div#index div#bodyindex ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Gracias con antelación. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Al final solucione con fast click jquery¡¡

[FastClick jQuery](https://github.com/dave1010/jquery-fast-click)

Gracias de todas formas espero que le ayude a otras personas.